# Lightdm display-setup-script with if-else-construct

Tags: lightdm

To configure my displays for lightdm, I use the `display-setup-script` option in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

If I point it to an actual script

```
if xrandr | grep -q "HDMI-1 connected"; then
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as eDP-1
else
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080
fi
```

it works just fine.

But if I use a one-liner like

```
display-setup-script=if xrandr | grep -q "HDMI-1 connected"; then xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as eDP-1; else xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080; fi
```

this fails. Why does this happen?